# SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am getting the exception above when I run an application. The application is using asp.net mvc 3 / C#. I made an mdf file and added it under App_Data folder in Visual Web Developer Express. I added connection strings to the web.config folder but when I run and browse to /store, I get the error above with the line `var categories = storeDB.Categories.ToList();` highlighted. My database contains 6 tables and one of them is Category.

Controller:

```
EventCalendarEntities storeDB = new EventCalendarEntities();

public ActionResult Index()  
{  
    var categories = storeDB.Category.ToList();  
    return View(categories);  
}
```

Connection strings in web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="EventCalendarEntities"
        connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
        Integrated Security=SSPI;
        AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\MvcEventCalendar.mdf;
        User Instance=true"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: make sure you have categories table?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This usually means a simple configuration issue:

- perhaps there genuinely is no such table
- perhaps the table is there, but there is no `dbo` scheme (it might be in `Fred.Categories`)
- perhaps the db is case-sensitive (which is fine), and the table is actually `dbo.CATEGORIES`

Any of these will cause the above exception. In particular, you state:

> My database contains 6 tables and one of them is Category.

Now to a *machine*, `Category` != `Categories`

Comment: I don't have any table called Categories. I have a table with the name Category.

Comment: @user522767 then you might want to tell that to Entity Framework, which is still looking for Categories.

Comment: public class EventCalendarEntities : DbContext  
{  
  public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }  
  public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }  
}

Comment: @user522767 you need to look at the EF model designer, and look at how that *class* (Category) maps to a storage table. In particular, look at the storage model.

Comment: I have changed, Now  var categories = storeDB.Category.ToList();

Comment: Where can I find the EF model designer?

Comment: @user522767 in the tags, you claim you are using Entity Framework; so presumably at some point you had the EF designer and dragged your tables onto it. Go back to that UI. Which is usually a double click on EventCalendarEntities in the solution file.

Comment: I added an mdf file created in SQL Server Management Studio as an Existing item to an App_Data folder created in Visual Web Dev Express. Of course, I downloaded the EFCodeFirst with the EntityFramework DLL from the Nuget site to my project.

Comment: The mdf file contains my tables - Order, Category, Event, etc

Comment: there is no such table as Categories but don't why I keep getting dbo.Categories

Comment: @user522767 the .edmx file; or .dbml if you are using linq-to-sql

Comment: I don't have this file in my project

Comment: @user522767 at *some point* you must be, to be using EF... *somewhere* you have a model that is defining `EventCalendarEntities`, `Category`, etc...

Comment: I have created the classes you mentioned above myself under the Model folder.Therefore I have, EventCalendarEntities.cs and Category.cs

Comment: @user522767 is this using code-first? You'll still need to tell it how to map that class to a table...

Comment: Untested; maybe something like: `        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().MapSingleType().ToTable("Category");
        }` in your entities class?

Comment: I am using EntityFrameWork Code-First using EntityFrameWork dll. I have made the Music Store by following the tutorial.(http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-4). Now I am just following the same tutorial to make an Event Calendar of my own but stuck with this problem.

Comment: I have found INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Categories, a base table. I am surprised here because I didn't create it.

Comment: @user522767 that isn't your table; DON'T DELETE IT

Comment: I have tested two databases( actually mdf files). The one I downloaded from the tutorial site and another one I created with SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio using a script from the tutorial site. The one I downloaded works fine but the one I made with the studio does not - the same error as above - "SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Genres'." I am thinking of an alternative without using the studio

Comment: Finally found a fix for "Invalid object name dbo.Categories" problem. I had to change all the table names and DbSet properties to plural. E.g. Category to Categories, DbSet<Category> Category to DbSet<Category> Categories. In the controller, I used an Entity object StoreDB like StoreDB.Categories.ToList(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: I had the same issue using Entity Framework Core 2; my `public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` class had the various `DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses` definitions which had to be changed to `DbSet<MyClass> MyClass` to allow linq queries to work as expected with the generated DB.

Answer (score 10):

Try using model builder class. It is the way to configure or explicitly define the mapping between table and model class.

In your entity/context class try adding this code

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("Category");
    }
```

It's a method. Make sure you are using all the including statements.

Answer (score 3):

Since this was still top search hit on the exception in April of 2018 and it led me to a solution, let me tack this on for a specific situation...

Our application is based on ABP and ABP.Zero, and we already have a pattern that fit [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5374550/7053468). While I bet explicit mapping in the OnModelCreating method (a la [Dhananjay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10186759/7053468)) would have worked perfectly, it seemed like ABP's mapping was working perfectly up to this point and I didn't want to break the pattern.

My solution was to add a table attribute to the entity class, and this settled EF's confusion.

```
using System;
using Abp.Domain.Entities;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Discovery.History
{

    [Table("HistoryRecords")]
    public class HistoryRecord : Entity<int>
    {
        public int ResearcherCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateSubmitted { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want to do to fix this is in you `Context class` you should have a method called `OnModelCreating`... make sure it has this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Proven,tested & verified for table with name category or any SQL keywords named table use ToTable to instruct specific table name

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Entity<category>().ToTable("category");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Class for mapping properties and keys without `this.Map.(a table in db necessary to mapping)`, EntityFramework expect you have one table named like Category but convert in plural, so "Categories"..  To resolve you can add `this.Map(in correct table existing in your DB)`.

Answer (score -1):

in your DbContext where you create DbSet change Categories to Category
I resolved same issue by this way

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. See [answer].