# Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting this error: [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.], but I can't catch where error is. I can retrieve other data from other tables, but not this.

conditions are:

connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="myStoreConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\myStore.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

context:

```
public class AdminMyStoreConnection : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

sql script to create database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserRoles] (
    [RoleId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [RoleName] NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoleId] ASC),
    UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([RoleName] ASC)
);
```

model:

```
[Table("UserRoles")]
public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

controller with index view:

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Customers.ToList());
}
```

view:

```
@using myStore.Helpers
@model IEnumerable<myStore.Areas.Administrator.Models.UserRole>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Roles management";
}

<h2>Roles management</h2>
<div class="admin-container">
<div class="bcontrol">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Roles")" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp;Create New Entry</a>
</div>

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort: "RoleId", canSort:true, canPage: true, rowsPerPage:20);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "tadmin",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    selectedRowStyle: "selected-row",
    columns:
        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("RoleId",
                        header: "ID " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "RoleId"),
                        style: "tadmin-id"),

            grid.Column("RoleName",
                        header: "Role Name " + Html.SortDirection(ref grid, "RoleName"),
                        format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Roles", new { id = item.RoleId })" >@item.RoleName</a></text>),

            grid.Column("Control", style: "tadmin-control", canSort: false,
                        format:
                        @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Roles", new { id = item.RoleId })" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"><i class="icon-edit"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Roles", new { id = item.RoleId })" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"><i class="icon-list"></i>&nbsp;Details</a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "Roles", new { id = item.RoleId })" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a></text>)
                 )

        )</div>
```

and error message:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.

Source Error:


Line 19:         public ActionResult Index()
Line 20:         {
Line 21:             return View(db.UserRoles.ToList());
Line 22:         }
Line 23:
```

and stack trace:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.UserRoles'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5296058    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1379
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +175
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +53
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +134
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +41
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
>   +10    System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +437
>
> [EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing
>   the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) +507
>   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute(ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) +730
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) +131
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   +36    System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +72
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator() +23
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   +40    System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369    System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +58
>   myStore.Areas.Administrator.Controllers.RolesController.Index() in
>   d:.projects\trains\myStore\myStore\Areas\Administrator\Controllers\RolesController.cs:21
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.b__41()
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.b__33()
>   +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.b__49()
>   +223    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +24    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +102    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +57    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +43
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +47    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9628700    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Just curious your positive it doesn't already exist in your Database right?

Comment: it already exist and have some rows

Comment: I would recommend letting the `Entity Framework` build your `database` via the `package Manager Console`, instead of scripting the Database. Additionally the error only occurs if the `Object` Table exists or doesn't exist. I'd assume that your EF is trying to attempt to create the table. but its already there.

Comment: sql server 2008
i'll try now for code-first

Answer (score 5):

The problem was unfortunately very simple - as i have 2 areas - main and administrator and respectively i have 2 types of data connection, i have only 1 connection string in webconfig. after i added second line for admin context and all works
thanks for attention )
so the problem was incomplete (misconfiguration) in webconfig

Comment: I am facing this issue when using a custom schema. The problem is, when you add new migration, 'dbo' schema name is set as DefaultSchema in the Migration.resx (designer) file. So even if the tables exist under my custom schema name, still, whenever the API is invoked directly after IIS restart or deployment, it somehow starts looking for 'dbo' schema and gives me this error. It works fine if the WebAPI is initialized via a call from another application. I dont have a solution yet. Someone recommended using implementing IDbCommandInterceptor to switch schema dynamically. I am evaluating that.

Answer (score 2):

This usually simply means a configuration issue

- perhaps there genuinely is no such table
- perhaps the table is there, but isn't the the dbo scheme
- perhaps the db is case-sensitive (make sure that both table names are spelled correctly

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories)

Comment: i have added to SampleData:
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<AdminMyStoreConnection>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AdminMyStoreConnection context)
        {
            var userRoles = new List<UserRole>
            {
               new UserRole { RoleName = "Administrator" },
               new UserRole { RoleName = "Customer" },
               new UserRole { RoleName = "CustomerVIP" }
            };
        }
    }
and System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new myStore.Models.SampleData());
now there any errors but there no this table in my solution

Comment: Please rephrase .. **Sampledata** has nothing to do with `scheme`, or `TableName` or `If (Table Exists)`

Comment: it seems that database is created somwhere and this is an error of topic ) so - if in Server explorer in this database no my table, where it can be?

Comment: You are using `Internet Application Template` yes?

Comment: no i have started from blank and use MVCStore lessons with my enhancements

Comment: Are you familiar with the `Package manager console` Then? and have you ran it?

Comment: so-so, i only may install packages ) i'll read about EF and package manager

Comment: You can follow these 3 steps in the `PMC`, **1** type `enable-migrations` , **2** `add-migration "migrationName"`, **3** `update-database -verbose`. Typing these should sync your database with the models you have defined in your MVC Project. **Careful!** This will override the SQL tables if they do not match models.

Comment: hm, this works fine - i can see my seed entries on admin backend, but i can't see table in visual studio in server explorer section

Comment: Is it a refresh issue or was there an error on the `Update-database` command?

Comment: no update-database work without mistakes, but there are data in browser - which i can retrive via webpage, and at the same time i can't see these datas after refreshing for several times either in server explorer or sql server object explorer. i've made new database and import old data - the same problem, table exists, data on webpage are, but i can't see them via visual studio

Comment: Check your defaultConnectionString in web.config file. just to be sure that your not creating .mdf files for a local db

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="myStoreConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Store.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: So, after reinstalling vs2012 i try to connect to db, all tables excluding UserRoles I can retrive, but this one takes now another error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. I apologize this is misconfiguration of SQL server (now using 2012)? why all tables are connect as localDB but this tries to connect non-local?

Comment: Theres 2 ways you want to configure the conection from `WEB.CONFIG` under the `<ConfigSections>` under `<connectionStrings>` set **`<add name="DefaultConnection"` connectionString="Server=`SERVERNAME`;Database=`DATABASENAME`;User Id=`USERID`;Password=`PASSWORD`;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`** or change it to accept windows security here is a link to show you other ways http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Answer (score -1):

Your `table name` in database must be the exactly same with `dbSet<> name` in dbContext  if not rerun the migration. (running `update-databse` before declaring the dbSets can lead to that problem)

Like below

[image]

Comment: The question was self-answered, so this is not the issue. And it's not true in a general sense. Tables can be mapped to classes and DbSets with entirely different names. That's the idea of an OR *mapper*.

Comment: The change doesn't make it any more applicable to the question. And it's still unclear what you're saying.