# Invalid Object Name in ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I'm currently trying to develop an application that allows you to track your spending as part of my class. However I run into the error "Invalid object name 'dbo.AccTransactions"

My Windows Form Code:

```
    string command = "Insert INTO dbo.AccTransactions (id, transact_id, payee, dateof, amount, category)"
                            + "Values (@id, @transact_id, @payee, @dateof, @amount, @category)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 1);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transact_id", 2);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payee", payeeTextBox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateof", DateTime.Today);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", Convert.ToDecimal(amountTextBox.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", categoryTextBox.Text);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

My Connection String:

```
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=IVY\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BudgetTracker;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

My database has the table "dbo.AccTransactions" and it performs perfectly in SSMS.

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: Could be a permission issue. If you're using a sql server user account  you should change your connection string, or add your windows account login. Make sure to  `grant select, insert, update, delete on dbo.AccTransactions to [<Your Domain>\<your user name>];`

Comment: Perhaps duplicated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725804/invalid-object-name-dbo-userroles

Comment: Are you missing the "Initial Catalog" in your connection string? What is the version of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: @achuthakrishnan I am using SQL Server 2012 and I don't think so. Would you kindle explain?

Comment: I believe what @achuthakrishnan means is you are missing the `Initial Catalog=myDataBase;` in your connection string. When you attempt to access your table, the connection defaults to the `master` database. Take a look here https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Comment: @mrtig I've added "Initial Catalog=BudgetTracker;" right after the Data Source in my connection string, yet it still throws the same error.

Comment: @MarioEzra - could you please update your question with the new connection string? Also, just to be clear, you created the table in SSMS while logged in as the same user you've specified in the connection string? If not, (say you connect with sa account), then you need to run that `grant` command I mentioned.

Comment: one thing you could try is run `SELECT GETDATE() Dt` query in code, while running profiler.

Comment: @mrtig I've updated the string, thanks for the notice. The connection is supposed to run using Windows Authetication, which I assume is the "Integrated Security = SSPI."

Comment: In your query, can you try to put "BudgetTracker.dbo.AccTransactions" and see.

Comment: Also, please try to remove "Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False" from the connectionString and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are missing database name in the connection string.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=IVY\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

try it by putting the name of your database in the following string.

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=IVY\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check that user who is running your program has an access to that table. Most probably you need to set your user as dbo since you accessing the table as dbo.AccTransactions.