# Connect Mvc3 project with a database

Tags: connection, models

I have problems to connect my model with database, I was reading tutorials, but any example works.

My files:

**Web Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CancionContext" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|Canciones.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Cancion.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace BibliotecaMusica.Models
{
    public class Cancion
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
    }

    public class CancionContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cancion> Canciones { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CancionesController**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BibliotecaMusica.Models;

namespace BibliotecaMusica.Controllers
{
    public class CancionesController : Controller
    {

        CancionContext db = new CancionContext();

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Canciones.ToList());
        }


    }
}
```

**View Index of CancionesController**

```
 @model IEnumerable<BibliotecaMusica.Models.Cancion>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th>
                Autor
            </th>
        </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Nombre
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Autor
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

    </table>
```

The database **Canciones.mdf** is already created and the table **Cancion** is created too.
I get the following exception **EntityCommandExecution was unhandled by user code**

In the browser the message is :
Invalid object name 'dbo.Cancions'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Cancions'.

Source Error:


Line 17:         public ViewResult Index()
Line 18:         {
Line 19:             return View(db.Canciones.ToList());
Line 20:         }
Line 21:
```

I don´t know what is wrong with my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your connection string. Check this answer

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/173375/3467053

Or in the server explorer you can open a new connection to your db and check the connection string that the wizzard generates.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem that I found is that I don´t know why if my model is 'Cancion' Visual Studio appends the letter 's' and then the model is converted to Cancions. Now is working but I have to rename my model to 'Cancions'