# SQL Exception: Invalid Object Name, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

Doesn't this usually mean that the table doesn't exist?

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'Categories'.
>
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   bool breakConnection, Action wrapCloseInAction)

The table is there though; im looking at it with a few rows filled in, what else could cause this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'dbo.Categories'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374482/sqlexception-0x80131904-invalid-object-name-dbo-categories)

Comment: Well in the table it does have the name (with Schema) of Master.Categories. Do I add this to a connection string, or somewhere else?

Comment: To have a complete question here, you need to show the SQL and fully describe the object you believe exists: what schema is it in, what's the default schema for the user, are you looking at the proper database etc.